# Using jq array slicing but encountering array error

Tags: jq

I have this on my attendees.txt as an example. Now I want to filter the name Jasmine until Mark such that it will only output the Name.

```
{
    "Attendees": [
        {
            "Name": "Joseph",
            "CreationDate": "2019-08-13T08:35:17+00:00"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Jasmine",
            "CreationDate": "2019-01-07T03:24:01+00:00"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Rebecca",
            "CreationDate": "2020-05-19T13:20:58+00:00"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Mark",
            "CreationDate": "2019-01-30T15:09:39+00:00"
        }
```

I can use the command below:

```
jq -r '.Attendees[1,2,3].Name' < attendees.txt
```

But what if i have a thousand line of Names and I want to filter just 300-500? How can I properly filter the range and only output the names? I entered the command below and it says Cannot index array with string "Name".

```
jq -r '.Attendees[300:500].Name' < attendees.txt
```

Or similarly if I need to filter the above Names using range, I encounter the same error.

```
jq -r '.Attendees[1:3].Name' < attendees.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Array/String Slice `[:]`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/StringSlice:.%5B10:15%5D) operation returns an array, you still need to select the sub-object values from it

```sh
jq -r '.Attendees[1:4][].Name'
```

Comment: To avoid constructing a new array, you could use `range`: `jq -r '.Attendees[ range(1;4) ].Name'`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to filter the name Jasmine until Mark

So first find their respective indices:

```
  .Attendees
  | map(.Name)
  | index("Jasmine") as $first
  | index("Mark") as $last
  | select($first and $last))      # if both must be present
  | .[$first: $last+1][]
```

Here's an alternative that (a) deals with the edge cases differently, and (b) illustrates how to avoid constructing a second array:

```
  .Attendees | map(.Name)
  | (index("Jasmine") // 0) as $first
  | (index("Mark") // length) as $last
  | .[ range($first; $last+1) ]
```